# Maximize a quadratic convex function with a symmetric structure

Tags: combinatorics, positive-semidefinite, discrete-optimization

Let $S = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 
B & A
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ be a positive semi-definite matrix with matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ being symmetric.
Let $y_{1}, y_{2} \in \{0,1\}^{n\times 1}$ be two binary vectors.

The optimization problem is to maximize the following quadratic convex function with binary constraints:
$$
\text{maximize}_{y_{1}, y_{2} \in \{0,1\}^{n\times 1}} 
\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
y_1 \\ 
y_2
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)^{\mathrm{T}}
S 
\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
y_1 \\ 
y_2
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr),
$$
i.e., selecting a principal submatrix to maximize the sum of entry values.

I wonder if it is possible to show that an optimal solution has $y_1 = y_2$? Since the problem is so symmetric, this seems a bit intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, with $n=1$: take $A = 1, B = -1$. The optimal solutions are $(1,0),(0,1)$.  A similar phenomenon occurs in general with $A = I, B = -I$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben! I see: negative $B$ will suppress $y_1$ and $y_2$ to take the same values. If we in addition know $B$ has positive diagonals, e.g.,  diagonals of $A$ and $B$ are all no smaller than $1$, I wonder if you have any sense whether the statement would be true or not? Thanks again!

Comment: @Stupid_Guy It's hard to say. The contribution from $A$ can always be increased by making $y_1,y_2$  be the same, the trick is whether $B$ can be chosen to sufficiently "incentivize" the asymmetry $y_1 \neq y_2$